# Prevent skin names from duplicating in my dxBarCombo1

Tags: delphi, devexpress

On form show I am adding skins to dxBarCombo1.

```
for I := 0 to cxLookAndFeelPaintersmanager.Count -1 do
  begin
  if (cxLookAndFeelPaintersmanager.Items[i].lookandfeelname <>  'UltraFlat')
  and (cxLookAndFeelPaintersmanager.Items[i].lookandfeelname <> 'Flat')
  and (cxLookAndFeelPaintersmanager.Items[i].lookandfeelname <> 'Standard')
  and (cxLookAndFeelPaintersmanager.Items[i].lookandfeelname <> 'Native')
  and (cxLookAndFeelPaintersmanager.Items[i].lookandfeelname <> 'Office11')
  then begin
  dxBarCombo1.Items.Add(cxLookAndFeelPaintersmanager.Items[i].lookandfeelname) ;
  (cxBarEditItem2.Properties as TcxComboBoxProperties).Items.Add(cxLookAndFeelPaintersmanager.Items[i].lookandfeelname);
  end;
```

Hiding and showing the main form just keeps adding the same skins all over again so I get lots of duplicates in the combo.

What must I write so these skins don't get added all the time ?

I tried on form close to clear the combo with:

```
dxBarCombo1.Items.Clear;
```

but it does not seem to work.

Annoying.

Comment: OT: **Please** use temporary variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if skin name is already in the combo box:

```
if (cxBarEditItem2.Properties as TcxComboBoxProperties).Items.IndexOf(
             cxLookAndFeelPaintersmanager.Items[i].lookandfeelname) = -1 then
     (cxBarEditItem2.Properties as TcxComboBoxProperties).Items.Add(
                  cxLookAndFeelPaintersmanager.Items[i].lookandfeelname)
```

Comment: Thank you very much